# How do you disable caching in jade or swig

Tags: node.js, express, swig, pug

I've been playing with express js lately and I'm loving it. My problem is that when I submit an invalid form a validation error message appears but when I reload the page the error message is still displaying I think the error message is being cached. Is there a way to disable caching in jade / swig and also is there a way to just specify which pages to cache and not to cache(like the form)?

sample code:

```
filename: index.js
// app.get('/form', index.getForm)
exports.getForm = function(req, res){
 res.render('form');
}

// app.post('/form', index.postForm)
exports.postForm = function(req, res){
 // express form validation goes here ...
 if(errors){
  res.locals.errors = errors;
  res.locals.form = req.body;
  exports.getForm(req, res);
 }else{
  res.redirect('/welcome');
 }
}
```

and here's my jade

```
filename: form.jade
 if error.email
  .error=error.email.msg
  input#email(type='email', name='email', value='#{form.email}')
 else
  input#email(type='email', name='email', value='#{form.email}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres no cache problems unless you are running express in production mode.

It looks like when you press `F5`, after the form error, your request is re-submiting the same form via post (with the error).

#### Option 1:

- AJAX `<3`

#### Option 2:

- Use 2 diferent jade templates, one for the `exports.postForm with
  errors` and another for the `exports.getForm`. **Something like:**

  ```
  exports.getForm = function(req, res) {
      res.render('form');
      }


  exports.postForm = function(req, res) {
      // express form validation goes here.
      if(errors) {
          res.locals.errors = errors;
          res.locals.form = req.body;
          res.render('form_fail');  <----
      }
      else {
          res.redirect('/welcome');
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this so there's no need to create 2 different templates for each forms? Thanks